# Laravel redirect user to playstore app of android when someone access a url(GET REQUEST) in browser of android device

Tags: laravel

I am trying to redirect a user to android playstore or ios playstore where my app is stored when they visit my website.I want to achieve this with laravel.

I got the status of the device they are using:

```
    $agent = new Agent();
    if($agent->isMobile()|| $agent->isTablet()){
        if($agent->isAndroidOs()){
            return "android";
        }
        elseif($agent->is('iPhone')){
            return "ios";
        }
    }
    else if($agent->isDesktop()){
        $browser = $agent->browser();
        echo "Browser:".$browser."<br>";
        echo "Platform:".$agent->platform()."<br>";
        echo "Version of Platform:".$agent->version($agent->platform())."<br>";
        echo "Device:"."Desktop";
        return redirect('http://google.com');
    }
    else{
        return "Couldn't identify";
    }
```

Here,is the output:
[preview of the output when I access in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMDXO.png)
Browser:Chrome
Platform:Windows
Version of Platform:6.1
Device:Desktop

The above code works fine.What I need now is,I want to find a way to redirect the user to store and display the app I specify in ios,android.

Can anyone give me the code to do that.I know that this can be done with the headers the server receive.But,I don't know how to use it in the code.

Please help.I want to do this in laravel 5.1.

Comment: https://github.com/jenssegers/agent seems to have Laravel support and you can easily detect the different mobile devices off this.

Comment: Yes,I'm using the same jenssengers/agent to detect device.But,I want to redirect to the store.Can you provide me the code to redirect to the app I specify?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my own question.When we open our application in of google play website and that link is redirected automatically to the playstore.

```
if($agent->isMobile()|| $agent->isTablet()){
    if($agent->isAndroidOs()){
        return redirect('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds&hl=en');
    }
    elseif($agent->is('iPhone')){
        return "ios";
    }
}
```

Found from:  [Opening app in Google Play from a redirect link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401247/opening-app-in-google-play-from-a-redirect-link)