# Making Ios and Android Images Button

Tags: html, css, image, button

I have two pngs. One is to download the application on IOS and another one is to get it on google play.

Now the problem is that I want to convert these images into buttons. So when they are pressed the respective buttons redirects the user to the app store and play store.

Comment: You need the relevant urls to link to. What have you tried? And does this help [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401247/opening-app-in-google-play-from-a-redirect-link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this answer will help you!

```css
.download_app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.download_app > div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.download_app > div a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.download_app > div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="download_app">
  <div class="play_store">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.vhv.rs/dpng/d/467-4672484_google-play-badge-play-store-logo-white-hd.png" alt="Download App">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="app_store">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.vhv.rs/dpng/d/586-5866978_download-on-the-app-store-button-png-transparent.png" alt="Download App">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```